# Implicit conversion c++ xcode4.6.2

Tags: c++

I am a beginner of c++, i dont know why the result of Rational r(2, 1) is "r == 0.5", i found the cotr not call the `operator()` function. why?

```
class Rational {
public:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

  Rational(int a = 2, int b = 1)
    {
        cout<< "cotr"<<endl;
        numerator = a;
        denominator = b;
    };

    operator double() const
    {
        cout<< "()"<<endl;
        return (double)this->denominator/this->numerator;
    };

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Rational r(2, 1);
    cout << "_____"<< endl;
    cout << r << endl;
    cout << r.numerator << " " << r.denominator << endl;
    double d = 0.5*r;
    cout << d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing the denominator by the numerator, swap the two in `operator double() const` :)

```
operator double() const
{
    cout<< "()"<<endl;
    return ((double)this->numerator)/this->denominator;
};
```

The ctor won't call the `operator double()` function, it is only called when you try casting your `Rational` to a `double`. i.e.:

```
Rational frac(5, 7);
double result = (double)frac;
```

## Edit

If you want more control over your output then you can overload the `operator<<' so you could feed your own data into cout.  Here is how I've implemented it:

Inside your class definition:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Rational& ra);
```

and somewhere in your source file:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Rational& ra)
{
    return stream << ra.numerator << ", " << ra.denominator;
    // or: return stream << (int)ra;
    // or: return stream << (double)ra;
}
```

then you can call:

```
cout << ra << endl;
```

Comment: operator int() const
        {
            cout<< "()"<<endl;
            return this->denominator+this->numerator;
        };                                                                                     Rational r(2, 1);
        cout << "_____"<< endl;
        cout << r << endl;

Comment: why r == 3, i don't use (int) switch

Comment: That is a *REALLY* good question... When I try compiling that line, it won't compile because the call to `operator<<()` is ambiguous.  I have no idea why it is compiling for you...  You could overload the "operator<<()" to print out the int (or double or numerator,denominator) or anything else though.

Comment: class Rational {
     public:
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
      Rational(int a = 2, int b = 1)
        {
            cout<< "cotr"<<endl;
            numerator = a;
            denominator = b;
        };
        operator int() const
        {
            cout<< "()"<<endl;
            return this->denominator+this->numerator;
        }; 
    };
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        Rational r(2, 1);
        cout << "_____"<< endl;
        cout << r << endl;
        cout << r.numerator << " " << r.denominator << endl;
        return 0;
    }

Comment: Aha!  I assumed you had overloaded `operator double()` and `operator int()`!  What is happening is that the compiler is seeing that your class has an overloaded cast to int and it knows how to stream int into cout so it implicitly casts it for you and prints it out.  See my edit above for how to overload the default << operator so you can have better control of what your class outputs to streams.

Comment: thank you, yes, when i use printf out, there is a warning:Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'Rational', I have known, thank you very much.